# Dropdown option change depends on time in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have a JSON with a list of item. The JSON have current time. Each menu item have start time and end time. I want to display the items depends on the time. Is it possible? I have created a fiddle for this. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vimalv86/HB7LU/28319/)

Please see the below JSON

```
{"time":"Thu Mar 23 4:10:44 -0700 2017","breakfast":{"start_time":"Thu Mar 23 1:00:00 -0700 2017","end_time":"Thu Mar 23 3:00:00 -0700 2017","soup":[{"id":"b_01","name":"BF_one"},{"id":"b_02","name":"BF_two"}]},"lunch":{"start_time":"Thu Mar 23 4:00:00 -0700 2017","end_time":"Thu Mar 23 6:00:00 -0700 2017","salad":[{"id":"l_01","name":"L_one"},{"id":"l_02","name":"L_two"}]},"dinner":{"start_time":"Thu Mar 23 7:00:00 -0700 2017","end_time":"Thu Mar 23 9:00:00 -0700 2017","meal":[{"id":"m_01","name":"M_one"},{"id":"m_02","name":"M_two"}]}}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the differences in date

For example your current time in JSON is

```
Thu Mar 23 4:10:44 -0700 2017
```

Setting this as your current time

```
var currenttime = new Date($scope.data["time"]);
```

Now you can loop through each property in your object and compare start time and end time with current time

```
for (var key in $scope.data) {
        if (key !== "time") {
        var starttime = new Date($scope.data[key]["start_time"]);
        var endtime = new Date($scope.data[key]["end_time"]);
        var startdiff = (currenttime - starttime);
        var enddiff = (currenttime - endtime);
            if(startdiff < 0 && enddiff < 0){

          $scope.text = ("Next activity \""+key+"\" in "+Math.abs(Math.round(((startdiff % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000))+"min");
          $scope.activity="Next";
          break;
        }
        else if(startdiff > 0 && enddiff > 0)
        {
            //Activity has finished
        }
        else{
            $scope.text = ("On going "+key);
          $scope.activity = key;
          break;
        }
        }
        }
```

if `startdiff > 0 && enddiff > 0`  condition is true --> Activity has finished

if `startdiff < 0 && enddiff < 0` condition is true --> You are between previous and next activity

else --> You have an on going activity

The line

```
Math.round(((startdiff % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000)
```

will give you difference in `minutes`

As this will always be a -ve value surround it in `Math.abs(...)`

Here is the **[FULL EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/HB7LU/28328/)**